# How can I render a numbered date field with the names not numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a date picker for an events section and I cannot fathom how to have a datepicker with the names of days/months/years rendered not numbers.

I am currently using

```
f.inputs "Event Date" do
    f.input :eventdate, :as => :date_picker, :use_month_names => true
end
```

It renders on the frontend:

2014-04-02

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the option `:date_select => true` in your `f.input` line?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_month) way to do it using rails helper:

```
= select_month(Date.today, field_name: 'eventdate')
```

Or [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type) (see date select):

```
= f.input :eventdate, as: :date, order: [:month, :year]
```

Comment: Link only answers are not considered proper on SO. You could offer that as a comment to the OP's question, however.

Comment: okay so if this was rendered how would it be rendered on the frontend?

Comment: For second case like this (see released on field): http://asciicasts.com/system/photos/482/original/E234I02.png

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the date in the deafult format, you could always write your own method like:

array = months("jan", "feb","mar", etc);
String DisplayDate= months[0] . "  " . dayIs . ", " . yearIs;

Will return:  jan 1, 2014

Comment: No.  It's generic.  But the concept applies.

Comment: That wouldn't be a very good way to do it in Ruby/Rails since the form `input` method has the facilities built-in to do what the user needs. The question needs a Rails-specific answer.